# C# Char.IsLetter() not working properly

Tags: c#, char, visual-studio-2015, letter

everyone.
I am sorry for my poor English.
I have quite a simple task:
Read a file char by char, and count every letter. Language doesnt matter.
At first, i used a string with all restricted characters:

```
"1234567890`~!@#$%^&*()_+-=!№;%:?*(){}[];:|',./<>?  "
```

It was a stupid idea, so i decided to use:

```
!Char.IsLetter(data[i].letter)
data.RemoveAt(i);
```

Didn't work. Even the following didn't work(well, i didn't expect it to)

```
                if(Char.IsDigit(data[i].letter) || Char.IsSymbol(data[i].letter)||Char.IsControl(data[i].letter) ||Char.IsNumber(data[i].letter) ||Char.IsPunctuation(data[i].letter) ||Char.IsSeparator(data[i].letter) ||Char.IsSymbol(data[i].letter) ||Char.IsWhiteSpace(data[i].letter))
                data.RemoveAt(i);
```

It still lets some numbers and sybols slip through.
The most annoying one is '\r', which i cant get rid of.
I need a solution that can tell if a char is a letter.
I am novice, so simpler means better.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there any chance your code was failing to check characters immediately following a removed character because you forgot an `i--`?

Comment: You definitely want to whitelist, not blacklist here.  `char.IsLetter` should work fine, like @Cyral's answer.

Comment: I'd think blacklisting actually is better considering he said language does not matter: 一番 and стоп should both bee seen as valid IMO.

Comment: IsLetter should work in your case.I'm going to ask something stupid.Are you using a **for loop** where your condition is **data.Count** and you remove element from a list?

Comment: I use a for loop for data.count.
As I said, it deletes some symbols like dot or comma;
thanks for reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `data` is actually a `List<Data>()`, and if your code looks like this:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < data.Count; i++)
            if (!Char.IsLetter(data[i].letter))
                data.RemoveAt(i);
```

Using

```
public class Data
{
    public char letter { get; set; }
}
```

Then you have a bug -- you will be skipping the test for each letter following a removed letter, because the call to `RemoveAtt(i)` will reduce the index of all subsequent list entries by 1.  Instead you should use [`RemoveAll()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
        data.RemoveAll(d => !char.IsLetter(d.letter));
```

Comment: THANK YOU!
You're genius.
This method works fine, except for '\r'
How can I exclude it?
||(data[i].equals('\r') doesnt work.

Answer (score 4):

To simply get a count of the letters in the array of objects:

```
data.Count(x => char.IsLetter(x.letter));
```

This uses the LINQ [`Count`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb338038%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method and calls `char.IsLetter` for the `letter` field to determine if each character should be added to the count.

**Example:** (With just a string and not an object array)

```
var data = "ABC_123_\r_%$#";
var count = data.Count(char.IsLetter);
Console.WriteLine(count);
```

Will print **3** as expected.

Note you must add: `using System.Linq;` to the top of your file if it is not already there.

Comment: Note that the OP doesn't seem to be working with a string but rather an array of objects containing a field or property called "letter".

Comment: @adv12 Right, I'll modify my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that your are modifying the collection during the iteration

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Example
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<char> data =  "1234567890".ToList();
        //This does not remove all the element!!!
        for (int i = 0; i < data.Count; i++)
            data.RemoveAt(i);
    }
  }
}
```

You need this

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
        List<char> data = "1234567890".ToList();

        List<char> toDelete = new List<char>();

         for (int i = 0; i < data.Count; i++)
            toDelete.Add(data[i]);

        for (int i = 0; i < toDelete.Count; i++)
            data.Remove(toDelete[i]);
}
```

or with fewer lines (As you see ,IsLetter works fine,it doesn't have a problem with \r\n)

```
 List<char> data = (Environment.NewLine + "1234567890").ToList();
 data = data.Where(l => char.IsLetter(l)).ToList();
```

Comment: Or use RemoveAll as @dbc suggests

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression instead

```
Regex.IsMatch(input, @"^[a-zA-Z]+$");
```

or simpler

```
Regex.IsMatch(input, "[a-zA-Z]");
```

Comment: While this is a solution, it is not a direct answer to the question.

Comment: Thanks for reply.
It works only for english letters.